# How to know if the user has blocked the bot in Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created a bot using Bot framework V4 and hosted in Teams.

My bot is available for all the users in the organization.

I want to know if someone blocked the bot.

Is there any API or any event from the bot to know the user ID if the Bot has been blocked?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you looked into doing this at all with the graph api? that is my assumption on how you would do it.

Comment: Hello @DanaV, I looked into graph API, where I found API that will return version installed but was not able to find the API which returns the list of users who have blocked the users.

Comment: I think I might know a way to do this, but it will depend if you have a conversation context?

Comment: Hello @HiltonGiesenow, Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Do you mean help with the blocking part, or the conversation context?

Comment: Hi - any answer for me on this?

Comment: Hello @HiltonGiesenow, help me with the Blocking part :)

Comment: Found any solution yet ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still testing this, so not sure if it really works, but I think if the user has uninstalled an app, then trying to get the "conversation members" will fail, whereas it would succeed otherwise. Code is something like this (C#):

```
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl), appId, appSecret);

MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);

var members = connector.Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(userConversationId).Result;
```

That might only work if they're -uninstalled- the app though, versus -blocked- the bot, but it's easy enough to test (I won't have a chance today though).

Comment: Were you able to test this out?

Comment: Hello @Hiiton, I tried blocking the bot with my ID and tried the about code and I am still able to get the members details when I pass conversation ID.

Comment: ah ok. I think this might only work for an "uninstall" then.